# How to detect "Recent Apps" system button clicks (Honeycomb+)

Tags: android, button, user-interface, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm wondering what method this button calls.

[image]

My game always pauses/resumes correctly except for when I use this button, its seems like this button doesn't call the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods of an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).
It works if I exit the game, go to another window(like the one on the picture) and then use this button to resume. But If I just press this button, when ingame, the game pauses but the thread dosnt resume like it does every other time, the game kind of just stands still on screen and flickers a bit.

Hard to explain but I hope I'm being sort of clear, if not, ask!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the implementation of the button. This is a fault in the game its implemention.

Comment: But it works as it should when I exits the game through the `"home"-button` and then enter it again through this `"windows-open"-button` . The only time it dosnt work is when I press the `"windows-open"-button` while in game, then press the window for the game right away. So it has to be some sort of difference in the way `onPause()` and `onResume()` is called here compared to how they are normally called.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

None of standard [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) methods is called when "Recent Apps" button pressed. Activity will stay active after list of recent apps popups. Through semi-transparent left part of this list you can even observe application animation is still running, if you running a game with some animation that didn't handle this situation properly. Actually many of games in Google Play didn't handle this situation properly, even good ones, like Angry Birds.

The only Activity method are getting called when user opens "Recent Apps" list (or returns from it) is [onWindowFocusChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) with boolean parameter `hasFocus`. When user open list of Recent App method `onWindowFocusChanged()` called with `hasFocus` equals `false`, and same method called with `hasFocus` equals `true` when user pressing Back in this list.

Comment: thank you, cleared it up a bit :) always good to know the machine your working with.

Comment: It seems that on Android 4.4.4, onPause/onStop are called when the recent apps button is pressed.

Comment: But onWindowFocusChanged will also be false if you open another activity within the app, so it doesn't necessarily help knowing that "Recent Apps" button was hit (also called the Overview button now).

Answer (score 11):

I have same problem, i resolved this problem as below.er

**Register button click broadcast for Home and RecentApp**

```
InnerReceiver mReceiver = new InnerReceiver();
IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, mFilter);
```

**Now BroadcastReceiver code**

```
class InnerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
            if (reason != null) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                        // Home Button click
                    } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                        // RecentApp or Overview Button click
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But Dont forgot to `unregisterReceiver` BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I've done the full implementation here in android for react native  https://github.com/evanjmg/react-native-home-pressed/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/evanjmg/HomeWatcher.java

Comment: @Lokesh why onRecentAppClick is called twice in some devices like it is working fine with OnePlus 6 running on Android 9.0 but with Redmi 4 running on Android 7.1 it is called twice.

Comment: @RahulSharma thanks for update, i will check and update answer soon

Answer (score 6):

To detect when 'Recent apps' button was pressed you can use Accessibility Service. You'll need to run your own Accessibility Service and receive events with type "TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED" and check event's class name.

1. Read about [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html) in android developer. Set up your own Accessibility Service, ask for permission from user.
2. In your Accessibility Service override method `onAccessibilityEvent()`
3. In this method you will receive `AccessibilityEvent event` object, this object contains all necessary information about an event that have just happened on your device.
4. We are interested in the ClassName. ClassName sometimes can be null so don't forget about != null check. 
   Package names of Recent apps window will vary depending on the version of Android:

   - Android 4.1: "com.android.internal.policy.impl.RecentApplicationsDialog"
   - Android 4.2 - 4.4: "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity"
   - Android 5.0 - 7.1: "com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity"  ("s" letter was added)

Don't know the class name for older devices but I don't think someone maintains them in 2017 ;)

So you will have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() != AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED || event.getClassName() == null) 
        return;

    String className = String.valueOf(event.getClassName());

    if (className.equals("com.android.internal.policy.impl.RecentApplicationsDialog")
            || className.equals("com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity")
            || className.equals("com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity")){
        //Recent button was pressed. Do something.
    }
}
```

I've tested it on the following real devices: LG, Nexus, Sony and virtual devices: Motorola, Samsung.

If someone knows exception for these class names please ping me.

Comment: This does work for detecting the recents app, but it doesn't trigger again to detect which app was brought to the foreground from that screen. Any insights?

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar problem, so, I needed to know when the user press the recent apps button (menu key button in old versions of android). After a several hours of research I didn't found an event to catch when the home button or the menu button is pressed. I found that it's take a longer time to call `onStop()` when the user press the home button, so I figured out a trick to distinguish between these tow buttons relating on time of response and overriding two methods:

@Override

```
public void onUserLeaveHint() {
    // do stuff
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    userLeaveTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
    isNotPower = true;
}
```

@Override

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (isNotPower) {
        defStop = System.currentTimeMillis() - userLeaveTime;
        if (defStop > 200 ) {
            //home button
        }
        if (defStop < 200) {
            //recent apps button
        }
    }
    isNotPower = false;
}
```

- The `isNotPower` parameter that's to check that not the power button is pressed- when the power button pressed the `onStop()` method is called but not the `onUserLeaveHint()`.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found is listent to Broadcast Action called "ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS".From the Google docs:

*Broadcast Action: This is broadcast when a user action should request a
temporary system dialog to dismiss.  Some examples of temporary system
dialogs are the notification window-shade and **the recent tasks dialog**.*

Working code:

```
IntentFilter intentFilterACSD = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                    //do what you want here
            }
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilterACSD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this only the problem with this specific game? Or is it with every game you play?

Beside the `onPause()` and `onResume()`, there is another cycle called `onStop()`. Maybe there are some fundamental things that are being done here. With the press of that "windows-open"-button, the game will probably not go into to `onStop`-state whereas pressing the "home"-button it will.

Comment: good point, will try tagging some methods and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if (!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app that unambiguously demonstrates the behavior of the **recent-apps** / **recents key** with respect to both Activities and Fragments.

(Any assertion that normal lifecycle events are not triggered by this key is patently false.)

In `onCreate()` the main **Activity** initializes an array for the logging of all known *Activity* lifecycle events and also fires the main Fragment alongside itself in a second FrameLayout.

In `onAttach()` the main **Fragment** initializes a separate array for the logging of all known *Fragment* lifecycle events.

For logging purposes, both *Activity* and *Fragment* treat `onWindowFocusChanged()` as just another lifecycle event.

Logged events are timestamped so a user 'pause' indication can be given when rendering (and rendering occurs inside `onWindowFocusChanged()` when `hasFocus==true`).

Here is what user sees when the test app is started:

[image]

After a few seconds user presses **recent-apps**, waits a few seconds, then presses it again to see the truth:

[image]

NB: If, instead of using the recent-apps button, the experiment is repeated by (a) pressing tablet off/on button (b) pressing Start 2nd Activity button(c) etc.,  identical results are yielded.

**Answer to OP:**
Apparently there is no code that can detect the actual pressing of the recent-apps key!

But it doesn't matter because the app needs to be correctly handling the associated lifecycle events anyway.