# Application Back button android

Tags: java, android, button

How can I detect when I press the return application button in android? it is on the right side of the home button on samsung s3. sorry I dont really know what is the name of the button.

Not the back button of the keyboard

Comment: You mean the back button?

Comment: the one that is used when you switch application not the back button on the keyboard

Answer (score 5):

It is called the Back Button. You can override its method to handle click events. Something like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // do stuff
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Back button pressed, exiting..");
        //Your code here..
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Like this. i checked if it is back button. you can look up for the right button constant inside 'KeyEvent' class.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the button for opening the Recent Apps (the one on the right in the image):

[image: The button at the right]

There's no way to overriding it. The only method you can intercept is the Activity's onWindowFocusChanged, which is called once the recent apps is displayed, but also is been called on a lot of other different situations.

Take a look here for more info:

[How to detect "Recent Apps" system button clicks (Honeycomb+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478826/how-to-detect-recent-apps-system-button-clicks-honeycomb)

And here if you want to avoid opening the recent apps (but it seems it doesn't work on Jellybean and up):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095749/1991053