# Recent apps button in android

Tags: android

I'm newbie in android development. I've created an android app which shows the current location, and I need to override the recent apps button in android and add some options, is that possible?

Comment: where is your work on developing the app?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478826/how-to-detect-recent-apps-system-button-clicks-honeycomb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible to override recent apps button in android?

Not from an ordinary SDK app.

You are welcome to build your own custom ROM that modifies the overview screen, then convince people to install your custom ROM on their devices.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem, so, i needed to know when the user press the recent apps button (menu key button in old versions of android).
after a several hours of research i didn't found an event to catch when the home button or the menu button is pressed.
i found that it's take a longer time to call onStop() when the user press the home button, so i figure a trick to distinguish between these tow buttons relating on time of response and overriding two methods:

@Override

```
public void onUserLeaveHint() { 
    // do stuff
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    userLeaveTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
    isNotPower = true;
}
```

@Override

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (isNotPower) {
        defStop = System.currentTimeMillis() - userLeaveTime;
        if (defStop > 200 ) {
            // when the home button pressed
        }
        if (defStop < 200 ) {
           // when the recent apps button pressed
        }
    }
    isNotPower = false;
}
```

- the isNotPower parameter that's to check that not the power button is pressed-
  when the power button pressed the onStop() method is called but not th onUserLeaveHint().