# How to disable home key in Activity programmatically Android

Tags: android, key

How can I disable home key in android in activity programmatically

I tried by `HomeKeyLocker.class` and used in activity like this:

```
new HomeKeyLocker().lock(this);
```

But this is not working in any device.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the home key. It is user's choice is they want to leave your application.

See detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443420/android-intercept-disable-recent-apps-button/40443451#40443451).