# What method is ran when user clears "Recent Apps" in Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I have a music player with a noncancellable notification. In my onDestroy, i have a clearNotification method. However when I clear the app by holding the home button and clear recent apps, the music stops but the onDestroy method is not ran because the notification doesn't clear.

So my question is, Is there any method that is ran when user clears "Recent Apps" in Android.

Comment: You could try with onWindowFocusChanged() as referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478826/how-to-detect-recent-apps-system-button-clicks-honeycomb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the best way would be to create a `Service` and look for the `onTaskRemoved` method to be called.

Look here for extensive conversation: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list

Here's the `Service` API I suggest using: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29

Comment: thank you worked perfectly , i was already using a service so just implemented onTaskRemoved

Comment: maybe you can add this as an edit that it doesn't work unless i do=:

 Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        musicService.clearNotification();
        super.onDestroy(); 
    }

and

 Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            musicBound = false;
            musicService.clearNotification();
}

Comment: interesting..so if you're clearing in `onDestroy`, what are you doing in `onTaskRemoved`?